# How to insert text into terminal buffer of nvim by :normal command?

Tags: neovim

In a normal buffer of nvim, the following ex command works.

```
:normal! GAabcd
```

This adds the text "abcd" to the current normal buffer.

But in a terminal buffer of nvim, the above ex command doesn't work!

```
:normal! GAabcd
```

This just converts the terminal buffer into '-- TERMINAL --' mode and the "abcd" isn't added!

Why isn't the text added? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I digged the neovim sources and maybe found the answer by myself.

In `edit` funtion of edit.c, there is the following comment.

```
bool edit(int cmdchar, bool startln, long count)
{
  if (curbuf->terminal) {
    if (ex_normal_busy) {
      // Do not enter terminal mode from ex_normal(), which would cause havoc
      // (such as terminal-mode recursiveness). Instead set a flag to force-set
      // the value of `restart_edit` before `ex_normal` returns.
      restart_edit = 'i';
      force_restart_edit = true;
    } else {
      terminal_enter();
    }
    return false;
  }
  ...
```

I think it means that it's not possible to enter terminal mode(insert mode) while processing *normal* commands in ex-mode. Therefore the text 'abcd' wasn't added in terminal mode but was just processed as *normal* commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct in that it's not possible to append text using `:normal! GAfoo`. However, in the interests of answering your last question, you *can* do this:

```
:normal! "0p
```

So if you happen to have what you need in a register, you can always paste it.